# How to make my own domain name like abc.def?

Tags: web, dns

I have seen some domain names like http://nadim.computer/ how could i get a domain name like that. any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create your own top level domain. Here is [a list where you can choose from](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains).